# Parallel Stream adding items to same array

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an array of Objects which I stream to use a function on each object to modify it and add it to a completely new array of Objects.

By using `.parallel()` the execution time speeds up 2 times, but I'm getting some `NullPointerException`s when looping over the new array.

I tried to debug it a few times without any success. It seems that this problem only occurs during the runtime. I tried implementing a synchronized function for adding the new objects to the list, but sadly it didn't work as well.

Can anyone give me a suggestion how to get this working? Thanks in advance!

Here is the code snippet:

```
private static final Object sync = new Object();
private ArrayList<Object> newList = new ArrayList<Object>();      

private void addNewObject(Object newObject) {
        synchronized (sync) {
            newList.add(newObject);
        }
    }

private Object mutateObject(Object oldObject) {
    // Do something with the object here
    return mutatedObject;
}

public ArrayList<Object> createNewList(ArrayList<Object> oldList) {
    oldList.stream().parallel().forEach(object -> addNewObject(mutateObject(object)));
    return newList;
}
```

Comment: Why do you add an parameter to the createNewList function without using it?

Comment: Fixed the example.

Comment: Consider using the built-in concurrent collections so that you don't have to write your own concurrency code. Also, use interfaces like `List<Object>` for your public interface instead of implementations like ArrayList

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider refactoring `createNewList` method to something like this:

```
public List<Object> createNewList(List<Object> oldList) {
    return oldList.parallelStream()
            .map(this::mutateObject)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If you look up into the [java.util.stream.Stream JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html) you can see that there is a few terminal operations, like `forEach`, `collect`, `toArray`, etc. In your question it's better to use the `collect` terminal operation because it handles synchronization internally, avoiding race condition situations, without any further implementation of synchronization.

Mapping objects with `.map()` (an intermediate operation of `Stream`) and collecting result to a final list in parallel solves this problem.

The `addNewObject` function and `sync` object should be removed, because it's not used anymore.

Comment: You can replace `object -> mutateObject(object)` with `this::mutateObject`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! I'll try it. What can I do if I would like to add a object multiple times to the new list?

Comment: @Robert You can always return a list from `.map()` (e.g. `.map(object -> Arrays.asList(mutateObject(object), mutateObject(object), ....))` operation and do`.flatMap(Collection::stream)` on the stream to transform list of lists to a single list.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak there’s no sense in mapping to a `List`, just to do `.flatMap(Collection::stream)` afterwards. Just do `.flatMap(object -> Stream.of(mutateObject(object), mutateObject(object), ....))` in the first place…